# Matlab Simulink symbol

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to develop an optical communication system using Matlab Simulink. As I've been through some examples, I found this symbol but no idea what that is.. Any clue? 
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Double click on the block. It should have name and description in the mask if it is from a library.

Comment: It's the [Pulse Generator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pulsegenerator.html) block in `Sample Based Mode`.  As @Navan says, double click on the block and the dialog that appears will tell you what the block is, and there's a `Help` button that will take you to the documentation.